сортировка вектора со своим классом
Есть код
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
class TestSon;

class TestBase{
protected:
TestBase() = default;
};

class InterfaceTest : public TestBase{
public: 
    InterfaceTest() = default;
    virtual int get_speed() const = 0;
    static std::shared_ptr<TestSon> test_son (){
    return std::make_shared<TestSon>();
    }
};

class TestSon : public InterfaceTest{
protected:
    int speed;
    TestSon(): speed(100){}
    int get_speed() const override {return speed;}
};

class Start{
protected:
    int distance;
    std::vector <std::shared_ptr<InterfaceTest> > start;
public:
    Start() : start(10){}
    template <typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<InterfaceTest> set_vec(const std::shared_ptr<T> &a){
        start.push_back(a);
    }
    int get_time(const int &i){
        int time = distance / start[i]->get_speed();
        return time;
    }
    bool vs_time(const int &i, const int &k){
        return get_time(i) < get_time(k);
    }
    void sort() {
        std::sort(start.begin(), start.end(), vs_time(...));
    }
};

и не могу понять как сортировать этот массив по функции, нормальный предикат не могу придумать,  может я вообще изначально не правильно это все реализовал.

Если я верно понимаю, что вы хотите, то вот так будет вполне достаточно:
void sort() {
    std::sort(start.begin(), start.end(), 
              [](auto a, auto b) { return a->get_speed() > b->get_speed(); });
}


спасибо, за ответ,  но это не совсем то, что нужно,  мне нужно высчитать время, в классе test,  есть скорость, а в классе start, дистанция, и по времени сортировать массив.
Понимаю, что самое простое добавить перечную время в класс Test,  и оттуда ее вызывать для сортировки, но вдруг можно что-то другое.

А вы не находите, что чем больше скорость, тем меньше время? Дистанция-то у вас одинакова! Так что вместо вычисления времени делением (а если на 0? :)) и сравнения оператором "меньше", не проще ли сравнивать сами скорости оператором "больше"? Это не одно и то же, если подумать?

согласен с вами, но это только шаблон проекта, в настоящем несколько дочерних классов, и каждый класс умеет сокращать дистанцию, по определенной ситуации и в самом простом варианте это выглядит так для каждого класса.
s(distance) * h(var) = u(speed) * t(time).
вот по этому и пытаюсь понять как высчитать время
